# Setting in Firefox to disable shift+click or ctrl+click of hyperlink?

Tags: firefox, hyperlink

In Firefox (as well as in Chrome), if you hold down the shift key while clicking a hyperlink, it causes the link to be opened in a new window. Similarly, if you hold down the Ctrl key while clicking a hyperlink, it causes the link to be opened in a new tab.

I was wondering if there is a setting in Firefox that I could change to disable this functionality? (i.e. if you hold down shift or ctrl while clicking a link, that it opens the link in the current tab and does not open it in a new window or new tab.)

I looked in the about:config area but couldn't find anything that could achieve this.

If anyone knows how to do this it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If there is any such functionality, it should be banned from usage just as the blink tag was. What's next? Will you block the rightclick so users cannot copy your images? And then will you block pageup-pagedown because they mess with your poorly-written popups?